# Subtotal & Grandtotal in Pandas pivots

Tags: pandas, pivot, xlsxwriter

[Data Currently Populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyH8r.png)

[Data Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlyCt.png)

Code snippet used :-

```
df["Average"] = df["Average"].astype("category")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('New.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

table1 = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Average'],index=['Manager','Cost'],aggfunc=[len],fill_value=0)

table2 = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Average'], index=['Manager','Cost'],aggfunc=[np.sum],fill_value=0)

table = pd.concat((table1, table2), axis=1)

table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')

table3 = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Average'], index=['Project','Cost'],aggfunc=[len],fill_value=0)

table4 = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Average'], index=['Project','Cost'],aggfunc=[np.sum],fill_value=0)

project_table = pd.concat((table3, table4), axis=1)

project_table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')
```

Please help me achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

You need create new DataFrame by `sum`, add new level for `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html), [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together, [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last add grandtotal by `sum`.

`Total` was changed to `A_total`, `B_total` for correct ordering.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Manager':['A']*10+['B']*5,
                   'Cost':['a']*5+['c']*5+['b']*4+['a'],
                   'Average':range(15)})

print (df)
    Average Cost Manager
0         0    a       A
1         1    a       A
2         2    a       A
3         3    a       A
4         4    a       A
5         5    c       A
6         6    c       A
7         7    c       A
8         8    c       A
9         9    c       A
10       10    b       B
11       11    b       B
12       12    b       B
13       13    b       B
14       14    a       B
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Manager','Cost'])['Average'].agg(['size','sum'])
df2 = df1.sum(level=0)
df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.index.get_level_values(0) + '_total', 
                                       len(df2.index) * ['']])

print (df2)
          size  sum
A_total     10   45
B_total      5   60

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()
df.loc[('Grandtotal', ''),:] = df1.sum()
print (df)
                 size    sum
Manager    Cost             
A          a      5.0   10.0
           c      5.0   35.0
A_total          10.0   45.0
B          a      1.0   14.0
           b      4.0   46.0
B_total           5.0   60.0
Grandtotal       15.0  105.0
```